# Error: The name 'E' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument. How to create generic function?

Tags: dart

I am trying to create a top level function:

```dart
Iterable<E> mapEnumerated<T>(Iterable<T> iterable, E Function<E>(int, T) fn) sync* {
  var index = 0;
  for (final item in iterable) {
    yield fn(index++, item);
  }
}
```

But, it reports error message: `The name 'E' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.`.

And then, I tried to change it to the following, the above error is gone and I have no ideas why, but I still can't use it:

```dart
Iterable mapEnumerated<T>(Iterable<T> iterable, E Function<E>(int, T) fn) sync* {
  var index = 0;
  for (final item in iterable) {
    yield fn(index++, item);
  }
}


void main() {
  List<String> strs = mapEnumerated([5, 6, 7], 
    (i, e) => (i + e).toString()
  ).toList();

  print(strs);
}
```

This will report error: `The argument type '(dynamic, dynamic) → String' can't be assigned to the parameter type '<E>(int, int) → E'`.

What is the proper way to implement this?

The following code works, but it's not a generic function at all:

```dart
Iterable<String> mapEnumerated(Iterable<int> iterable, String Function(int, int) fn) sync* {
  var index = 0;
  for (final item in iterable) {
    yield fn(index++, item);
  }
}


void main() {
  List<String> strs = mapEnumerated([5, 6, 7], 
    (i, e) => (i + e).toString()
  ).toList();

  print(strs);
}
```

Reference: the original code is from https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32467. I am just not sure how to implement it as a generic function.

Comment: My first instinct was to change `mapEnumerated<T>` to `mapEnumerated<E, T>` but that didn't help, either. `E` being `String` does not want to apply to the function parameter's type. Someone with a deeper understanding of Dart generics can hopefully shed more light here.

Comment: @GazihanAlankus thanks for the reply. The code is from https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32467. I just don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type variable `E` is only introduced in the function type of the `fn` argument, so it is not available outside of that.

The `fn` function here is declared as accepting a generic function, so you would not be able to call it with `(i, e) => (i + e).toString)`, because that function is not itself generic.

You can rewrite your function as:

```
Iterable<E> mapEnumerated<T, E>(Iterable<T> iterable, E Function(int, T) fn) sync* {
  var index = 0;
  for (final item in iterable) {
    yield fn(index++, item);
  }
}
```

This introduces the `E` type variable on the `mapEnumerated` function, so it can be used in the return type of that function.